# Radare2 - changing stdin during binary debugging

Tags: debugging, radare2

I'd like to know how to change stdin multiple times for the given binary for debugging purposes.
I know I can launch the application with

```
r2 -r profile.r2 -d binary
```

Where, inside the profile.r2 file I have

```
program=binary
stdin=./path/to/some/file
```

But I'd like to know how, if at all possible, to switch stdin so that I can supply multiple different inputs during a **single debugging session**

Will I have to use `r2pipe` and its interface or is there a simpler way of achieving this in radare2?
If not possible in radare2, how would I go about doing this with `gdb`?

Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
I can simply make a named pipe with `mkfifo progin`

and set

```
stdin=progin
```

in my radare profile file.
Then i can feed my inputs to the binary one-by-one with `cat file1 >> progin` or `echo 123 >> progin`
every time the binary attempts to read something from stdin.

Just note that, radare2 will appear to hang when starting if the pipe is empty, so we gotta feed the first input for radare2 to startup. The next call to `read` will block until more data is available in the pipe, allowing us to supply a different input all while debugging in a single session.

NOTE: The pipes are prone to breaking so recreating them might be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dd` command or the `:dd` one if using r2frida to change any filedescriptor at runtime.

Comment: Thanks, but i was trying more to supply multiple program controlled inputs to the debugee. But thanks for the input, still dont know all the radare2 commands